# How do I send messages from 1 channel to another channel?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I was looking and looking and looking and most of the codes seems to work but when I do this is the result:

> Object reference not set to an object instance.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace ConsoleApp1.Modules
{
    public class code : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        [Command("test")]
        [RequireBotPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageRoles)]
        [RequireUserPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageRoles)]
        private async Task test()
        {




           await _client.GetGuild(470026969963167765).GetTextChannel(470026969963167767).SendMessageAsync("Message");

        }
    }
}
```

This one of the codes that I tried to use.

Comment: Which line is reporting the `NullReferenceException`? I'm assuming the await, but you should split each function call down and then you can debug easier.

Comment: ehh I tried that but not sure if it what you meant I pretty new so idk

Comment: I splitted every command and figured out the error comes from GetTextChannel()

Comment: Your client doesn't seem to be logged in for one, unless you've just removed that code. If it is logging in fine then your issue will be with that guild not existing on your bot.

Comment: context.client*